# Configuring Trac to work with Apache and WSGI on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, mod-wsgi, trac

I'm trying to install Trac on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. I have followed the instructions [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#InstallingTrac) and have tested the standalone server which works fine. However, it would be preferable to run Trac on the existing Apache 2.4 service.

I have downloaded and installed mod_wsgi as part of the Apache service, but I run into some trouble when following the [instructions given](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI) to set up Trac with mod_wsgi.

All the provided scripts and file-paths assume that Trac is being installed on a *nix server. I followed the 'special instructions' for installing Trac with mod_wsgi on Windows, but as you can see, they just provide a link to the binaries and then point you back to the *nix instructions.

The given script is as follows:

```
import os

os.environ['TRAC_ENV'] = '/usr/local/trac/mysite'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/usr/local/trac/mysite/eggs'

import trac.web.main
application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

I presume `/usr/local/trac/mysite` becomes the Trac Environment created with `trac-admin /path/to/project initenv` (in my case, I used `C:\TracEnvironment` for the trial run)

I am not sure what to replace `/usr/local/trac/mysite/eggs` with since there is no `eggs` folder in `C:\TracEnvironment`, nor can I find one anywhere in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\trac` where all the key files appear to be stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Egg-cache was in `%AppData%\Roaming\Python-Eggs\`

My adjusted script is

```
import os

os.environ['TRAC_ENV'] = 'C:\\TracEnvironment\\'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python-Eggs\\trac-1.0-py2.7-win32.egg-tmp\\trac\\'

import trac.web.main
application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

My httpd.conf required the following lines to be added

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac C:/TracEnvironment/trac_script.wsgi

<Directory "C:/TracEnvironment">
    [Whatever permissions you want]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Perhaps the recent documentation edits to [TracModWSGI](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI?action=diff&version=59&old_version=54) and [TracOnWindows/Advanced](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows/Advanced?action=diff&version=24&old_version=21) were partially yours. One of the Trac devs added some additional suggested changes that you can see in the preceding diffs.

Comment: @RjOllos Yeah, I figured that I might as well update it to help anyone else in my position... or myself the next time I have to do it :)